# is it neccasary to call LruCache.evictAll(); in onDestroy() method?

Tags: java, android, memory-management

For better memory management, do i need to call LruCache.evictAll(); when finishing an activity or does android take care of that?
(my LRuCaches caches images in a listView)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html#evictAll()

Comment: Well, to startoff, there is *No* guarantee that your `onDestroy()` will be called either.. More  or less, Android OS will handle such things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you only should do that if you really want for some reason clear the cash. LRU should take care of that for you if necessary.